# How to authorize Node.js API with Azure AD?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, mean-stack, azure-active-directory

We have application that is written using MEAN stack. Right now application is using home grown authentication. We are trying to replace it with Azure AD authentication.

There is nice article [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/) that shows how to configure Angular for Azure Authentication using ADAL.JS library. This will protect client side resources. In the example the server side APIs are written using .Net Web API and OWIN is used to protect Web API. So OWIN is responsible for validating Bearer token send from the client.

With MEAN stack the server side API are written in Node.js, so how do we protect Node.js API if we switch to Azure AD? Is there any Node module available from Microsoft? Any Example will greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have recently implemented one with my react application with nodejs backend and with `passport-azure-ad`

***You can refer to my post here for both authorization and authentication
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58761942/8238968***

You can find the key values for **BearerStrategyOptions** at https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-nodejs/blob/master/node-server/config.js

Also, FYI I used the following common endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration for **identityMetadata**

```
const BearerStrategyOptions = {
  identityMetadata,
  clientID,
  validateIssuer,
  issuer,
  passReqToCallback,
  allowMultiAudiencesInToken,
  audience
};
```

For Authorization:

```
passport.use(
    new BearerStrategy(BearerStrategyOptions, function(token, done) {
      console.log("verifying the user");
      console.log(token, "was the token retreived");
      findByOid(token.oid, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          // "Auto-registration"
          console.log(
            "User was added automatically as they were new. Their oid is: ",
            token.oid
          );
          users.push(token);
          owner = token.oid;
          return done(null, token);
        }
        owner = token.oid;
        return done(null, user, token);
      });
    })
  );
```

And to authorize the routes use the following code in your api

```
 passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {session: false})
```

Done! Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides a [passport](http://passportjs.org/) plugin, [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad).

> *passport-azure-ad* is a collection of Passport Strategies to help you integrate with Azure Active Directory. It includes OpenID Connect, WS-Federation, and SAML-P authentication and authorization. These providers let you integrate your Node app with Microsoft Azure AD so you can use its many features, including web single sign-on (WebSSO), Endpoint Protection with OAuth, and JWT token issuance and validation.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/) configures the AAD tenant info in the angular scripts which will expose these info from clients, it increases risk of revealing sensitive info.

You can consider store all info and operate authentication and authorization flows at backend in Node.js applications. And only expose Apis for frontend angular clients.

You can refer to the sample provided by O365 at [gitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-Connect) which leverages ADAL module.
And the main authentication and authorization flows are written at https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-Connect/blob/master/authHelper.js.

And the usage with access token in requests in Node.js you can refer to https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-Connect/blob/master/requestUtil.js

## update

I find the ADAL.js is designed follow the oauth2 authentication via response type of id_token. Which means it will only expose tenantId and AAD application clientId which are not so sensitive info. And the ADAL.js will store the access_token and several user info in html5 sesstionStorage. you can refer to http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/ and http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ for more info.

About the ADAL.js usage, you can parse the access token via JWT in your backend app with your own logic, and you can refer to the sample at https://github.com/matvelloso/AADNodeJWT.

Meanwhile, in my opinion, you can separate your MEAN app into 2 independent Azure Web Apps. One to build your Angular App as the frontend, and other host your Expressjs Node.js App as the backend of our entire web app architecture.

In the backend Web App service, you can use Azure Active Directory as an authentication provider to protect your Web Apis. refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/ for details.

And in the frontend Web App service, you can use `adal.js` and `adal-angular.js` in the Angular app for authentication and authorization.You can refer to the frontend part of https://github.com/matvelloso/AADNodeJWT.

When you successfully finish the authentication flow, the `adal.js` plugin will store the `idtoken` in `html5 sesstionstorage`, so we can leverage this token to request the backend app which is protected by AAD:

```
var token = sessionStorage.getItem('adal.idtoken');
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization= 'Bearer '+token;
$http.get('https://<your_backend_apis>').then(function (data){
      console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: thanks Gary Liu, and that was my next question because article configures the sensitive information in js file and this sensitive information is available on client side. How come Microsoft promote such design pattern? Same solution was published  here on channel 9 by Vittorio Bertocci https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/AngularJS-Module-for-Microsoft-Azure-Active-Directory-Authentication may be i missing something here

Comment: and i also found an article that shows how to protect Node API https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/  however my question about ADAL.js is still there, is it valid design pattern?

Comment: I find the ADAL.js is designed follow the oauth2 authentication via response type of `id_token`. Which means it will only expose `tenantId` and AAD application `clientId` which are not so sensitive info. And the ADAL.js will store the `access_token` and several user info in `html5 sesstionStorage`. you can refer to http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/ and http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ for more info

Comment: About the ADAL.js usage, you can parse the `access token` via `JWT` in your backend app with your own logic, and you can refer to the sample at https://github.com/matvelloso/AADNodeJWT.

Answer (score 0):

For authorize Node.js server with Azure AD, you can use the **adal-node** library in node.js.

Following Sample will demonstrate authentication Node.js with Azure AD, step by step:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-authorize-Nodejs-fdc580ed