# How can I get the azure AD roles in my Backend?

Tags: node.js, azure, passport.js, roles, passport-azure-ad

I am developing a backend in node express where I use the passport-azure-ad library to protect the routes of my api, is there any way to access the roles defined in Azure Ad for the application and validate them in the routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the above requirement you may need to follow the below workaround.

We can get our Azure AD log details by using [***MS GRAPH Programmatically***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

***SAMPLE CODE:-***

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let directoryAudit = await client.api('/auditLogs/directoryAudits/{id}')
    .get();
```

Also you can get roles which has assigned in Azure AD by using below [***MS GRAPH query***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in your code.

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/appRoleAssignments
```

For complete setup please refer the below links:

- MS DOC:-  [***Call the Microsoft Graph API in a Node.js console app***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-console).
- SO THREAD:- [***How to issue tokens from Azure AD in a Node.js App/API?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766958/how-to-issue-tokens-from-azure-ad-in-a-node-js-app-api)